# Matlab : How to write a variable of type int16 into a variable of type double?

Tags: matlab

I'd like a 16 bit fixed representation of 1.5 using scaling factor of 2. So I type into command window

```
>> a = int16(1.5 .* 2)

a = 3
```

the following assgiment statement causes variables to be forced int16?

```
>> b = a

b = 3

>> b = b / 2

b = 2  % But I expected 1.5
% why integer operation? 
% I want the variable b to become double type.
```

How Can I have the variable 'b' has double type?

Comment: Use `b=double(b)/2`, I think `b=b/2.0` should also work.

Comment: You can check the data types of your variables with `whos`

Comment: good answers. `whos` is great! before your comment, I'm not sure whether the variable `b` is double or int16. from `whos`, I have just learned that the variable `b` of type int16 becomes one of type double by typing the statement `b=double(b)/2`.